# Xamarin Forms: For what kind of projects is Reactive UI preferable?

Tags: mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms, system.reactive, reactiveui

I want to know, for which kind of projects can we use ReactiveUI mvvm framework. I know FreshMvvm can pretty much be used for most of the projects but I want to know is there any specific scenarios where its beneficial to use Reactive UI?

I am not really sure , if this question is against the rules of stackoverflow, but I just want to get a clear idea about under which scenarios can we prefer Reactive UI.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is mostly open to opinions and I don't think there is a clear answer. You'll have to evaluate each framework and decide what is best for you.

Both FreshMvvM and ReactiveUI are MvvM frameworks. They don't impose a distinct limitation on what kind of project you can make unless they don't support a platform that you need. Consult the respective sites for each framework to see which platforms are supported.

[ReactiveUI](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI#-reactiveui)
[FreshMvvm](https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm)

It's also worth mentioning that ReactiveUI takes advantage of Reactive Extensions. It encourages "functional" style programming vs. imperative.

I don't see any reason why either MVVM framework would limit the type of application you can make as long as you have the supported platforms you want. These are just frameworks to help with the design patterns of MvvM*.

If you can ask more specific questions about your hesitations, that would be great.

Note* FreshMvvm was designed with Xamarin.Forms in mind, while ReactiveUI supports other non-mobile platforms as well.

Comment: I am planning to create Xamarin Form app so I was wondering which one to pick as my mvvvm framework for the project. I am still new to ReactiveUI. Does reactive extensions anyway increase the efficiency of the app?